# Spring boot JWT + HTTP Session: is it possible?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, http, session, jwt

I have a Spring Boot application on the server side with an Angular App on the client side. I'm using JWT but I would like to be able -for a particular feature- to preserve state between two POST requests (saving an object as a session attribute). To be honest I'm new to Spring/Angular and I just chose this scheme because I needed to have my app running as soon as possible. I'm just now realizing that JWT is fully stateless. I found some documentation on how to enable Http Sessions on a Spring boot app using JDBC, well the database and it's tables are being created, but I still get a new sessionID on every request. In the WebSecurity config I changed the SessionCreationPolicy to  ALWAYS, and the SessionFixation to 'NONE' but it still doesn't work. From the client app I'm only sending the JWT token (idk if the SessionID can be sent from Angular to the server).

Considering the hours and hours I have been reading about this, I guess this is impossible to achieve, JWT and Sessions can't be combined... But well, I just wanted to be sure before giving up. Can orient me a little on this topic?

Comment: hi @imnotthatrobot, did you find a solution to this problem? I want to implement the same in one of my project.

Comment: hi @AbhilashRamteke, I was no able to finally implement this solution. I had some interesting proposals from some AI chat but nothing well justified and tested by a real person.

Answer (score 0):

I've done some research on this topic and I found some stuff. I warn you that there seem to be conflicting opinions, but I hope that could help you.
In [this article](https://medium.com/@prashantramnyc/difference-between-session-cookies-vs-jwt-json-web-tokens-for-session-management-4be67d2f066e) on Medium, about differences between JWT and Session Cookie approach. Here is a small excerpt:

> **Combining both approaches?**
> Some programmers have attempted to combine the Session Cookie based and JWT based approach, and use one for authentication and the other for looking up authorized resources.
> Session based or JWT based approaches are complete in themselves to effectively manage session management individually, and *there is no clear advantage in combining them together (unless there is a specific use case that this solves)*.

[This other article](https://devops.com/session-tokens-vs-jwts-choosing-your-session-management-solution/) on Devops, instead, states:

> ...
> Generally, *JWTs* win out based on performance: They enable faster authorization and more interoperability with external apps. But they demand more developer investment to address their security complexities and ensure that the right guardrails are in place to prevent vulnerabilities.
> *Session tokens*, on the other hand, enable more control but introduce some latency. While they provide stronger guarantees that each individual request is authorized and is simpler to implement securely, their bottleneck on the server-side database validation comes with a latency overhead that might ruin the user experience for highly responsive applications.
> While this framework can be helpful shorthand for summing up JWTs and session tokens, it falls into the trap of pitting security against performance, as if the two are mutually exclusive.
> But forward-thinking leaders in growth and security alike recognize that the best solutions leverage security to optimize user experience and accelerate product adoption and growth. One of the best ways to do that with session management is to combine JWTs and session tokens into a powerful hybrid.
> **Combining JWTs and Session Tokens**
> To date, there are a few different ways companies have combined session tokens and JWTs.
> One of the simplest ways is to return both a session_token and a JWT when a user starts a session.
> The session_token is a static value that is good for the lifetime of the session (stored server-side), while the JWT has its own, shorter-lived expiry.
> In this setup, expired JWTs can be passed to the session API in order to retrieve a fresh JWT, and the servers ensure that the underlying session is still active before passing back a new JWT. If the user logs out, this revocation of access will take place within whatever token age you set for your JWT. In other words, you only call the server when the JWT expires or before granting access to particularly sensitive actions.
> Configured this way, this approach to session management greatly reduces the performance overhead while also protecting you and your end users from the risk of authorizing actions based on stale information. Instead of a tradeoff, JWTs and session tokens are leveraged together to optimize both security and performance.

In the end, I forward you [this section of a project tutorial](https://www.callicoder.com/spring-boot-security-oauth2-social-login-part-2/#securityconfig) that implements a short-lived cookie to store some parameters needed for security between a client server (a react app) and a backend server (a Spring Boot app).
 It doesn't implement session, but if I understand correctly your use case, I think could help  you.